# Why I can override `Event` with `MouseEvent` in function signature?

Tags: typescript

I have code
[https://www.typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFk4jgc2gKAG99lTkAHOAZyoAoIAuZAUQDcJwAaZbAW0eRUwUUDgCUTVgHtgAEwDc+AL758CKSCHJeWXNGRMMuvFGQBeZERJlKNJjACuIBGGAb6TdFIdUIbDmDcfAJCIiDi1qTEZDHI6ppSADYQAHSJUji0AEQAHnlZ3KkIicABABqFKcWl4ACaYvKWMSpKiqo62CYptnQgEADuLOzg2XCy1ONUWWLcWcHT8kA):

```js
interface IManager
{
    pass(e: Event, name: string): void; // inteface require *base* `Event`
}

const manager : IManager = 
{
    pass: function(e: MouseEvent, name: string) // typo error `Event` with more *specialized* `MouseEvent`
    {
        console.log("pos=", e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }
};
manager.pass(new Event("Some"), "name");
```

Wht TS allow me to do this? In `IManger` I require *base* `Event`, but further in implementation I mistakenly override type with more *specialized* `MouseEvent`. Now in implementation I can use `MouseEvent` specific properties `.clientX`, `.clientY`, ..., but that wasn't my intention.

I expected error: **manger doesn't implement `IManager` interface, `pass(...)` method signature doesn't match**.

Why TS doesn't throw error? What I missing here? How to write it to avoid such mistakes?

Comment: TS checks method params *bivariantly* (see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance)) which is unsafe but intentional.  See the linked q/a for more info and for how to avoid it

Comment: @jclaz thanks, you solved all my `coding` problems :)

Comment: @jcalz by the way, because you have a lot of SO points, what should I do with this question? I agree that it's duplicate, I have option to delete it, should I delete it? In my opinion my question is formulated more searchiable friendly. What are SO community standarts according to that?

Comment: Generally [one should not delete duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265737/2887218) because they help people in the future

Comment: @jclaz now you solved all my problems. I leave it as it is.